# How to load items in combobox from data stored in database

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

I am trying to load some item in combo box from the data stored in the database.
I have a button when clicked it populates company details in the relevant boxes properly.
and in the database i have three fields like

```
Dev = Yes or No
Fin = Yes or No
Net = Yes or No
```

where Dev is the field name and Yes is the text stored in the database.

i read all details for a company in reader so i tried something like this.

```
If reader(14).ToString = "Yes" then
   combobox1.items.add("Developer")
else if reader(15).ToString = "Yes" Then
   combobox1.items.add("Finance")
Else if reader(15).ToString = "Yes" Then
   combobox1.items.add("Networking")
End iF
```

It is not working any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: it doesn't load the items in the combo box and no error message of any sort...?

Comment: what value does reader(14 or something) returns when debugging using a break point.? have you checked with any case sensitive problems.?

Comment: reader(14) holds Yes or No

Comment: Does the control flow enters into that particular If statement.?

Comment: In debug do you see it add and item?   Try combobox1.items.add("Test").

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You are  checking this condition `else if reader(15).ToString = "Yes" Then` twice in your code, May be this could be a problem for you.

```
If reader(14).ToString = "Yes" then
   combobox1.items.add("Developer")
else if reader(15).ToString = "Yes" Then
   combobox1.items.add("Finance")

'--------------\/ May be this could be your problem. 
Else if reader(15).ToString = "Yes" Then     
   combobox1.items.add("Networking")
End iF
```

Consider this too, This may solve your casing problems.

```
    If reader("Dev").ToString.ToUpper() = "YES" then
       combobox1.items.add("Developer")
    else if reader("Fin").ToString.ToUpper() = "YES" Then
       combobox1.items.add("Finance")
    Else if reader("Net").ToString.ToUpper() = "YES" Then     
       combobox1.items.add("Networking")
    End iF
```

Comment: there's no casing problem i've checked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Equals` to check the values, the name for the field, and `ElseIf` (all together) for the conditions, and check if that solves your problem:

```
If reader("Dev").ToString.Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Developer")
ElseIf reader("Fin").ToString.Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Finance")
ElseIf reader("Net").ToString.Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Networking")
EndIf
```

But it would be better if you store the values in a different way in your database. For example, you can store only the type in one field. being "Dev", "Fin" or "Net" for example. Or even better, have a new table with the id, values and codes and only use the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
If reader(9).ToString = "yes" Then
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Developer")
ElseIf reader(9).ToString = "no" Then
End If
If reader(11).ToString = "yes" Then
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Finance")
ElseIf reader(11).ToString = "no" Then
End If
If reader(10).ToString = "yes" Then
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Networking")
ElseIf reader(10).ToString = "no" Then
End If
```